Bean not found when using @ConditionalOnProperty and @ComponentScan
I'm working on a Spring Boot application and I'm facing an issue with bean creation. I have a Car class annotated with @ConditionalOnProperty and @Component. Here is the relevant part of my code:
Car.Java
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "car.enabled", havingValue = "true")
@Component
public class Car {
    // logic
}


AppConfig.java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("base.package")
public class AppConfig {
    // nothing inside
}


I have verified that the @ConditionalOnProperty logic returns true. However, when I run my client code, I get a "Bean not found" exception. To troubleshoot, I modified the AppConfig class as follows:
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {  
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "car.enabled", havingValue = "true")
    public Car car() {
        return new Car();
    }
}

With this change, the Car bean is found and everything works correctly.
Question:
Why is the Car bean not being created when using @ConditionalOnProperty with @ComponentScan? How can I fix this issue while still using @ComponentScan?
Additional Information:
I am sure that the property car.enabled=true is set correctly. Also Car class in present inside the back.package.

I am sure that the property car.enabled=true is set correctly well apparently it isn't else the bean would have been there. Where have you set the property?

In my application.property file located in src/java/resources folder

src/java/resources is the wrong place. That should be src/main/resources.

Oopsy typo. I also wanted to mean src/main/resources. Sorry for the error. Do you have any idea about this weird behavior @M.Deinum

Show your folders, and content of your file.
